# Dynamic control creation vs Static Control performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have couples of pages which is Q&A, baiscally is just for reference, they can't add question or answer.
The Answer will not show until the Question is being clicked, and the Q&A is formated in a format that Question will be bolded, underline etc.

These Q&A is not going to change a lot, but for different customer they will have different Q&A.

The previous developer made all Q&A to show and hide using server-side and is static on the Page.

Thinking in the future when I create a new Q&A page for another customer and I will need to write proper style for each Q&A (underline for question, bold it, break, assign id, line by line).

I wonder if it's a nice idea to put all Q&A into a text file, then use a parser to parse the text file and create all Q&A dynamically?  So if I need to change the formatting for each Q&A how it display, I can just modify how I create the control. In that case it's a lot easier to make all controls client-side.

But the other thing is, this page will be used by many users at the same time.  So I wonder if dynamic control creation will impact the page performance a lot?  Is it even worth it to make it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

performance isn't problem until (1)it's defined and (2)it's measurable.

as for dynamic vs. static files. That really depends on how simple or complex you want the solution to be. If it's just Q&A with formatting then html & css makes much more sense then a dynamic server side solution.

Comment: hmm I guess this is true, right now is just really sample.  I guess I will just modify all old script to associate with ID so I can use with css and java script. Thanks.

Comment: Id's are required. some conventional html and class naming would be  enough to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Building the control dynamically sounds like a fine idea and shouldn't cause a problem performance wise. Reading the data for the questions out of a text file does not. There are a ton of issues with that approach (concurrency & locking, performance of IO). You should use a database technology to store and retrieve the data.

If you use a user control to build the question, you can mitigate any possible performance issues by using output caching on the user control. This way, the sets of questions may not have to be regenerated over and over if they don't need to be.

Comment: Reading question from text file I am thinking to read it in application start and cache it into a static list, so all other user will just read from the same list...

Comment: You can cache from a database too. I still recommend against using a file. Based on load, many application threads can start at the same time. Having your app access the file system introduces security concerns that are best avoided if possible. You're re-inventing the database, let someone smarter than you worry about that stuff and use a DB provider.

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic placeholder also makes it easy to add / and keep controls / control states across post backs.

If this option would make life easier for you, have a look at this Dynamic Control Library

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx